# resetting iteration over dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to implement a code that will reset the iteration over a dictionary given a condition inside the current iteration. It should look something like this

```
for index in range(1, max_index):
    for phrase in rules:
        for constituents in rules[phrase]:
            if mem_list[-index:] == constituents:
                del mem_list[-index:]
                mem_list.append(phrase)
                # reset all of the three for loops
```

The variables are as follows:

- index: integer that is decided in another function
- rules, dictionary with nested lists bound to the keys
- phrase, key for the dictionary
- constituent element inside dictionary entry
- mem_list, list with elements that may occur inside dictionary entries.

I have to use the (ordered) dictionary for this. Does anyone have some good ideas to reset my iterations given the condition?

Thank you guys for thinking with me in advance!

EDIT: The solution turned out to be pretty mundane: Recursively call the function inside the if statement so that the entire function will run with the new variables. code below:

```
def foo(rules, mem_list, max_len)
    for index in range(1, max_index):
        for phrase in rules:
            for constituents in rules[phrase]:
                if mem_list[-index:] == constituents:
                    del mem_list[-index:]
                    mem_list.append(phrase)
                    foo(rules, mem_list, max_len)
    return mem_list
```

Comment: Short: You can't. Iterators can only be consumed once. Easiest way might be to put your construct in a function that you restart if you need to reset.

Comment: seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here: can you please update your question with sample input, and expected output based on sample input ?

Comment: Found the solution, I just didn't realise it was rather simple. When I make a function out of this and call it recursively in the condition it does the trick just fine. Thank you guys for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a function from it, and return the mem_list

```
def asd():
    for index in range(1, max_index):
        for phrase in rules:
            for constituents in rules[phrase]:
                if mem_list[-index:] == constituents:
                     del mem_list[-index:]
                     mem_list.append(phrase)
                     # reset all of the three for loops
                     return mem_list

some_list =  asd()
```

Comment: So I have to keep calling the function recursively? Cause i need to keep resetting until the if statement isn't reached anymore

Comment: recursion seems to do the trick just fine! Thanks for your input